# Increase uicollectionview cell size when it is selected in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios8, mkmapview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am doing an application where I need to increase/zoom collection view cell. I am giving link to image. I need to implement similar to the image given below. Please help me someone. Thanks in advance.

http://40.media.tumblr.com/e338d087cdd7e26b4ceda7129ae33987/tumblr_njh29zUfwA1r2wjwko6_1280.png

Answer (score 0):

In your current scenario, I don't think there is any need to change the cell size on tap. You can play with your view's (inside cell) frame.

> 1. Just create the cell with the *same size* equal to the *selected cell size*.
> 2. Make the background of the cell clear color.
> 3. In non-selected state, make the view's *y* around *25 pixels* lower and hide that *horizontal line*.
> 4. On selection, stretch the view's *y* to around *20 pixels* upper side, show that *horizontal line* and change the height accordingly.